# Конвертировать данные от tilda

Tags: python

Работаю с вебхуком конструктора сайтов tilda . Получаю следующие данные:

```
b'name=clientName&payment=%7B%22sys%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22systranid%22%3A%220%22%2C%22orderid%22%3A%222069588462%22%2C%22products%22%3A%5B%22Slime+Box%3D4500%22%5D%2C%22amount%22%3A%224500%22%7D&formid=form229172915&formname=Cart'
```

Необходимо их конвертировать в формат utf-8 и сохранить в переменную для отправки post запросом.

Вместо сохранения данных в переменную было бы отлично сохранить их в словарь, если это возможно (например, {"name": "clientName", "payment": "")

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

a = b'name=clientName&payment=%7B%22sys%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22systranid%22%3A%220%22%2C%22orderid%22%3A%222069588462%22%2C%22products%22%3A%5B%22Slime+Box%3D4500%22%5D%2C%22amount%22%3A%224500%22%7D&formid=form229172915&formname=Cart'
res = dict(x.split("=") for x in a.decode("utf8").split("&"))
res = {k:unquote(v) for k,v in res.items()}
print(res)
```

получим:

```
{'name': 'clientName', 'payment': '{"sys":"none","systranid":"0","orderid":"2069588462","products":["Slime+Box=4500"],"amount":"4500"}', 'formid': 'form229172915', 'formname': 'Cart'}
```